# To compare 2 excel files using python

Tags: python, excel

I have a excel file with following fields

> Software_name , Version  and Count.

This file is a inventory of all softwares installed in the network of an organization which was generated using LANdesk.

I have another excel file which is an purchase inventory of these softwares which is generated manually.

I need to compare these sheets and create a report stating whether the organization is compliant or not.

Hence how do i compare these two files.

there are instances like Microsoft Office is mentioned as just office and 'server' is spelt as 'svr'

How do go about with it?

Comment: As much as I appreciate the advertising for `xlrd` etc, the `excel` tag is quite irrelevant. You have 2 files/databases/webpages which you have no problem reading in as (for example) a list of lists, one has standardised product names, the other one has non-standard product names ...

Comment: Why don't you use the built-in Spreadsheet Compare tool to compare the differences in the spreadsheets? It gets installed along with Excel when you install MS Office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step as SeyZ mentions is to determine how you want to read these Excel files. I don't have experience with the libraries he refers to. Instead I use COM programming to read and write Excel files, which of course requires that you have Excel installed. This capability comes from PyWin32 which is installed by default if you use the [ActiveState Python installer](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads), or can be [installed separately](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/) if you got Python from Python.org.

The next step would be to convert things into a common format for comparing, or searching for elements from one file within the other. My first thought here would be to load the contents of the LANdesk software inventory into a database table using something quick and easy like SQLite.

Then for each item of the manual purchase list, normalize the product name and search for it within the inventory table.

Normalizing the values would be a process of splitting a name into parts and replacing partial words and phrases with their full versions. For example, you could create a lookup table of conversions:

```
partial               full
--------------------  --------------------
svr                   server
srv                   server
SRV                   Stevie Ray Vaughan
office                Microsoft Office
etc                   et cetera
```

You would want to run your manual list data through the normalizing process and add partial values and their full version to this table until it handles all of the cases that you need. Then run the comparison. Here is some Pythonish pseudocode:

```
for each row of manual inventory excel worksheet:
    product = sh.Cells(row, 1) # get contents of row n, column 1
                               # adjust based on the structure of this sheet

    parts = product.split(" ") # split on spaces into a list

    for n, part in enumerate(parts):
        parts[n] = Normalize(part) # look up part in conversion table
    normalProduct = " ".join(parts)

    if LookupProduct(normalProduct): # look up normalized name in LANdesk list
        add to compliant list
    else:
        add to non-compliant list

if len(non-compliant list) > 0:
    TimeForShopping(non-compliant list)
```

If you have experience with using SQLite or any other database with Python, then creating the LANdesk product table, and the normalize and lookup routines should be fairly straightforward, but if not then more pseudocode and examples would be in order. Let me know if you need those.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!. Ya, it would be very helpful if you can give us more examples.

Comment: Hi Vinod, I will give some examples, but what do you have working so far? Do you know how to create an SQLite database and copy your LANdesk worksheet into it? Do you have code to read through your manual software list worksheet?

Comment: Hey Todd, can we do this without SQLite? The normaliszing table can i make that a file?

Comment: Sure. Make another worksheet or workbook as your normalizing table. Make one column the partial word and a second column the full word. Then your normalizing process would load that worksheet into a Python dictionary, each partial word is a key and the full word is its value. eg {"partial":"full"}. Additionally you would load the LANdesk list into a Python dictionary with the product name as the key and the other fields in a tuple as the value: {"product name": ("version", count)}.  So as I asked before, how much do you have working already?

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries to manipulate .xls files.

[XLRD](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) allows you to extract data from Excel spreadsheet files. So you can compare two files easily. (**read**)

[XLWT](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) allows you to create some Excel files. (**write**)

[XLUtils](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlutils) requires both of the xlrd and xlwt packages. So, you can **read & write** easily thanks to this library.

Comment: We are actually using this these libraries to do this. But the problem is that the Strings becomes very difficult to compare ,as 1 is manually written.