# Identify matches between 2 excel files

Tags: python, excel, loops, openpyxl

I've got 2 excel files pertaining to parameters of a set of individuals.
I'm trying to copy the parameters from one file to another based on the individuals id.

To do that, I'm looping over both files cell by cell to match cases based on individual id and parameter id.

I've built the following code for that, but it's only finding matches for the first case.
Can't see where I'm making the mistake. I'm still trying to ensure that at least the individuals id match properly

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/miguelnobremenezes/Documents/Code/Excel_fill/45_24M_ECOCARDIOGRAMA.xlsx')
ws= wb.active

wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/miguelnobremenezes/Documents/Code/Excel_fill/echo_CB.xlsx')
ws2= wb2.active

r = 0
r2 = 0
c = 0
c2 = 0

patient = 0
patient2 = 0
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    print(patient)
    r2 = 0
    #if patient == None:
     #   break
    r += 1
    c = 0
    for cell in row:
        c += 1
        if c > 100:
            break
        elif r > 1 and c > 1:
            patient = ws.cell(row = r, column = 1).value
            header = ws.cell(row = 1, column = c).value
            
            
            for row in ws2.iter_rows(min_row=0):
                if patient2 == None:
                    break
                r2 += 1
                c2 = 0
                for cell in row:
                    c2 += 1
                    if c2 > 100:
                        break
                    if r2 > 1 and c2 > 1:
                        patient2 = ws2.cell(row = r2, column = 1).value
                        header2 = ws2.cell(row = 1, column = c2).value 
                        print(r2)
                        print(patient)                      
                        print(patient2)
                        if patient == patient2:
                            print("Match")
                            print(patient)
```

Comment: can you upload a sample of the two files in order to reproduce this code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To compare 2 excel files using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370341/to-compare-2-excel-files-using-python)

Comment: I think you have too many loops. It's also not clear from the code what the structure of the files is and in what cases they should match.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.